# App crashes after receiving notification using @react-native-firebase/messaging

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Iam trying to implement notification using @react-native-firebase/messaging in react native app.The App returns the FCM token ,but when a notification is received the app closes.

I got below error in crashlytics

Unable to instantiate service io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService" on path: DexPathList

Below are the library versions used in app.

```
"@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^7.6.7",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.4.3",
"@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^8.4.9",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^7.8.11",
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "^0.63.3",
```

android/build.grade

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "30.0.0"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 30
    targetSdkVersion = 30
    supportLibVersion = "27.0.0"
    // googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.+"
    // androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"
    // firebaseVersion = "+"
    // firebaseMessagingVersion = "+"


}
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
   // mavenCentral()

}
dependencies {
    classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'// Google Services plugin
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.3.0'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
    }
    maven {
        // Android JSC is installed from npm
        url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
    } 
  //  maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

   
 
}

}
```

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
  compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.awrostamani.starterkit"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode project.env.get("ANDROID_VERSION_CODE").toInteger() 
    versionName project.env.get("ANDROID_VERSION_NAME")
    multiDexEnabled true
}
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
    }
}
signingConfigs {
    debug {
       
    }
    release {
      
  }
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
        // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
        // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        
    }
}

// applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
        // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        }

    }
}
 }


dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
//noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
// implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
// implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
// implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
// implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.2'
// implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.2.2'
 implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.3.0'
  implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.+"

debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
  exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
}

debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
    exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
}

debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
    exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
}

if (enableHermes) {
    def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
    debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
    releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
} else {
    implementation jscFlavor
}
}

 // Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
 // puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
from configurations.compile
into 'libs'
 }

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform- 
android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

  // Google Play services Gradle plugin
  com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Notification code

```
import notifee from "@notifee/react-native";
import messaging from "@react-native-firebase/messaging";

export default class Notifications {
 static onMessageReceived(message) {
 const { type, timestamp } = message.data;

 if (type === "order_shipped") {
  notifee.displayNotification({
    title: "Your order has been shipped",
    body: `Your order was shipped at ${new Date(
      Number(timestamp)
    ).toString()}!`,
    android: {
      channelId: "orders"
    }
  });
 }
 }

static onMessage = messageHandler => {
alert("test");

  messaging().onMessage(this.onMessageReceived);
};
  static setBackgroundMessageHandler = messageHandler => {
  messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(this.onMessageReceived);
  };
static getToken = async () => {
try {
  const fcmToken = await messaging().getToken();
  Notifications.checkPermission();
  if (fcmToken) return fcmToken;
  else return null;
 } catch (err) {
  console.log("--->Token error from Notifications:" + err);
  return null;
 }
};

 static onTokenRefresh = refreshHandler => {
return messaging().onTokenRefresh(fcmToken => {
  refreshHandler(fcmToken);
 });
};

static checkPermission = () => {
messaging()
  .hasPermission()
  .then(enabled => {
    if (enabled) {
    } else {
      messaging()
        .requestPermission({
          alert: true,
          announcement: false,
          badge: true,
          carPlay: false,
          provisional: false,
          sound: true
        })
        .then(() => {})
        .catch(error => {});
     }
   });
 };
}
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue

Comment: If you have a problem with react-native-firebase, has it occurred to you to open an issue on the react-native-firebase issue tracker with full details and (for a cloud message crash) the JSON you can send to the FCM REST API to trigger it along with the native stack trace from `adb logcat`? That would actually get you help :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove the below code from the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
 <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseInstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Comment: I'm surprised this isn't in the official `react-native-firebase` docs

Comment: This was really helpful

Comment: Hi there! I maintain react-native-firebase. This isn't in the docs because it is a terrible idea, sorry. It means that you will no longer receive notification events at all because no intents are filtered.

Comment: @TuanAnh use current versions of react-native-firebase according to the documentation? I mean that seriously. There is no need for anything in the AndroidManifest in current versions, and Firebase Cloud Messages will be received without the app crashing. Script that builds demonstration here: https://github.com/mikehardy/rnfbdemo/blob/master/make-demo.sh

Comment: @MikeHardy, you should know it's incredibly easy to integrate other notification frameworks, but firebase integration with expo is taking me months.

Comment: That's odd @ObynoPac because as maintainer over there on react-native-firebase I host config plugins for Expo for react-native-firebase, so it should just work with Expo. Notifee has a config plugin as well if I recall? I don't think it even took us months to write the things, something must be wrong...

Comment: I guess so too, what are the possible reasons why the app crashes on notification, also do you have any sites i can go to or any steps you can give me as guide so I can successfully implement this on my app.

Comment: "what are the possible reasons why the app crashes on notification", it would be inefficient to speculate, it is much better to collect the thread stack trace from the crash and diagnose the problem directly by determining what code is crashing based on the stack trace. Every project has different notification requirements, step by step guides would vary so much they would not be helpful. The project documentation should be sufficient for a basic integration and if not, we can work to change that

Answer (score 1):

Just remove those services in the AndroidManifest.xml file and that's it. Don't filter the event intents.

Comment: Removed it, didn't work

Answer (score 1):

**Mike Hardy** is actually right.

I got myself into this problem because I have followed old tutorials.

**Removing the following services that I have wrongly added** resolved the problem:

```
  <!-- [START firebase_service] -->
  <service
    android:name=".java.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
  </service>
  <!-- [END firebase_service] -->
```

I hope this will help others :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE" tools:node="remove" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.oppo.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"  tools:node="remove"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" tools:node="remove" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


<application>
<meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_channel_name"
                android:value="YOUR NOTIFICATION CHANNEL NAME"/>
        <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_channel_description"
                    android:value="YOUR NOTIFICATION CHANNEL DESCRIPTION"/>
        <!-- Change the value to true to enable pop-up for in foreground on receiving remote notifications (for prevent duplicating while showing local notifications set this to false) -->
        <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_foreground"
                    android:value="false"/>
        
        <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color"
                    android:resource="@color/white"/> 

        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationActions" />
        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
<application>
```